# MenuItem tinting on AppCompat Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appcompat, tint

When I use drawables from the `AppCompat` library for my `Toolbar` menu items the tinting works as expected. Like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_clear"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha"  <-- from AppCompat
    android:title="@string/clear" />
```

But if I use my own drawables or actually even copy the drawables from the `AppCompat` library to my own project it will not tint at all.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_clear"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha_copy"  <-- copy from AppCompat
    android:title="@string/clear" />
```

Is there some special magic in the `AppCompat` `Toolbar` that only tint drawables from that library? Any way to get this to work with my own drawables?

Running this on API Level 19 device with `compileSdkVersion = 21` and `targetSdkVersion = 21`, and also using everything from `AppCompat`

`abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha_copy` is an exact copy of the `abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha` png from `AppCompat`

**Edit:**

The tinting is based on the value I have set for `android:textColorPrimary` in my theme.

E.g. `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#00FF00</item>` would give me a green tint color.

**Screenshots**

Tinting working as expected with drawable from AppCompat
[image: Tinting working as expected with drawable from AppCompat]

Tinting not working with drawable copied from AppCompat
[image: Tinting not working with drawable copied from AppCompat]

Comment: Both styles have the same parent? What if you extend the top style with your own?

Comment: There is no difference in the styles. The only difference is the drawable, which are both .png files

Comment: The drawable looks like an a exact copy of the original AppCombat drawable in the code?

Comment: They are png files, which I copied. They are exactly the same.

Comment: So where exactly does your code differ from the original if it has the same style and same image?

Comment: That is kind of what this question is all about.

Comment: What do you mean by *tinting works as expected*. What's the tint color and where is it defined?

Comment: can you put screenshots of what is happening?

Comment: Updated post with screenshots explaining the issue

Comment: I added a solution that does not use reflection/view lookup or any other ducktapes. It's clean and flexible, take a look at my post

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Because if you take a look at the source code of the TintManager in AppCompat, you will see:

```
/**
 * Drawables which should be tinted with the value of {@code R.attr.colorControlNormal},
 * using the default mode.
 */
private static final int[] TINT_COLOR_CONTROL_NORMAL = {
        R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha,
        R.drawable.abc_ic_go_search_api_mtrl_alpha,
        R.drawable.abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha,
        R.drawable.abc_ic_commit_search_api_mtrl_alpha,
        R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha,
        R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha,
        R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha,
        R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha,
        R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_selectall_mtrl_alpha,
        R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha,
        R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha,
        R.drawable.abc_ic_voice_search_api_mtrl_alpha,
        R.drawable.abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha,
        R.drawable.abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha
};

/**
 * Drawables which should be tinted with the value of {@code R.attr.colorControlActivated},
 * using the default mode.
 */
private static final int[] TINT_COLOR_CONTROL_ACTIVATED = {
        R.drawable.abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha,
        R.drawable.abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha,
        R.drawable.abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha
};

/**
 * Drawables which should be tinted with the value of {@code android.R.attr.colorBackground},
 * using the {@link android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode#MULTIPLY} mode.
 */
private static final int[] TINT_COLOR_BACKGROUND_MULTIPLY = {
        R.drawable.abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult,
        R.drawable.abc_cab_background_internal_bg,
        R.drawable.abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult
};

/**
 * Drawables which should be tinted using a state list containing values of
 * {@code R.attr.colorControlNormal} and {@code R.attr.colorControlActivated}
 */
private static final int[] TINT_COLOR_CONTROL_STATE_LIST = {
        R.drawable.abc_edit_text_material,
        R.drawable.abc_tab_indicator_material,
        R.drawable.abc_textfield_search_material,
        R.drawable.abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha,
        R.drawable.abc_btn_check_material,
        R.drawable.abc_btn_radio_material
};

/**
 * Drawables which contain other drawables which should be tinted. The child drawable IDs
 * should be defined in one of the arrays above.
 */
private static final int[] CONTAINERS_WITH_TINT_CHILDREN = {
        R.drawable.abc_cab_background_top_material
};
```

Which pretty much means they have particular resourceIds whitelisted to be tinted.

But I guess you can always see how they're tinting those images and do the same. It's as easy as set the ColorFilter on a drawable.

Comment: Ugh, that's what I was afraid of. I didn't find the source code for AppCompat in the SDK, that's why I didn't find this part myself. Guess I'll have to browse on googlesource.com then. Thanks!

Comment: I know it's a tangential question but why is there a white list? If it can do the tinting with these icons then why can't we tint our own icons? Plus, what's the point in making almost everything backward compatible (with AppCompat) when you leave out one of the most important thing: having action bar icons (with custom color).

Comment: There is an issue for this in Google's issue tracker that has been marked as fixed, but it doesn't work for me, but you can track it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37127128

Comment: They claim this is fixed, but it’s not. Gosh, I loathe Android theme engine, AppCompat and all the crap associated with it. It only works for “Github repo browser” sample apps.

Answer (score 107):

After the new Support library v22.1, you can use something similar to this:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        Drawable drawable = menu.findItem(R.id.action_clear).getIcon();

        drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.textColorPrimary));
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_clear).setIcon(drawable);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I'd say that in this case the old `setColorFilter()` is way preferable.

Comment: @mvai , why setColorFilter() is more prefferable?

Comment: @wilddev brevity. Why bother the support DrawableCompat class when you can go menu.findItem().getIcon().setColorFilter() ? One liner and clear.

Comment: The one-liner argument is irrelevant when you abstract away the entire logic into your own TintingUtils.tintMenuIcon(...) method or whatever you want to call it. If you need to change or adjust the logic in the future you do it in one place, not all over the application.

Comment: There is no need for different logics to tint and no need to not change in future.

Comment: Two notes here - (1) you need to call `unwrap` to get the original drawable type; and more importantly, (2) wrapping a drawable stores the colored instance in a (small but relevant) cache for appcompat resource loader - this means that the next time you try to load the same drawable, you get the recolored instance.

Answer (score 102):

`app:iconTint` attribute is implemented in `SupportMenuInflater` from the support library (at least in 28.0.0).

Tested successfully with API 15 and up.

Menu resource file:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
        app:iconTint="?attr/appIconColorEnabled"        <!-- using app name space instead of android -->
        android:menuCategory="system"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_themes"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_palette_white_24dp"
        app:iconTint="?attr/appIconColorEnabled"
        android:menuCategory="system"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="@string/menu_themes"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_help"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_help_white_24dp"
        app:iconTint="?attr/appIconColorEnabled"
        android:menuCategory="system"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="@string/menu_help"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />

</menu>
```

(In this case `?attr/appIconColorEnabled` was a custom color attribute in the app's themes, and the icon resources were vector drawables.)

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer! Also, please note `android:iconTint` and `android:iconTintMode` do not work, but prefixing with `app:` instead of `android:` works like a charm (on my own vector drawables, API >=21)

Comment: If calling programmatically: note that `SupportMenuInflater` won't apply any custom logic if the menu isn't a `SupportMenu` like `MenuBuilder`, it just falls back to regular `MenuInflater`.

Comment: In this case, use `AppCompatActivity.startSupportActionMode(callback)` and the appropriate support implementations from `androidx.appcompat` will be passed into the callback.

Comment: This is the right answer!

Answer (score 87):

Setting a `ColorFilter` (tint) on a `MenuItem` is simple. Here is an example:

```
Drawable drawable = menuItem.getIcon();
if (drawable != null) {
    // If we don't mutate the drawable, then all drawable's with this id will have a color
    // filter applied to it.
    drawable.mutate();
    drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    drawable.setAlpha(alpha);
}
```

---

The above code is very helpful if you want to support different themes and you don't want to have extra copies just for the color or transparency.

**[Click here](https://gist.github.com/jaredrummler/ec7dfb73f3235ad8e951)** for a helper class to set a `ColorFilter` on all the drawables in a menu, including the overflow icon.

In `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` just call `MenuColorizer.colorMenu(this, menu, color);` after inflating your menu and voila; your icons are tinted.

Comment: I've been banging my head against my desk trying to figure out why all of my icons are being tinted, thanks for heads up about drawable.mutate()!

Comment: Nothing helped until now. Love u bro <3

Answer (score 32):

I personally preferred this approach from this [link](http://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2014/11/11/android-changing-action-icon-colors-with-android-5-0s-drawable-tinting/)

Create an XML layout with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_something"
    android:tint="@color/color_action_icons_tint"/>
```

and reference this drawable from your menu:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/option_menu_item_something"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_something_tined"
```

Comment: This is my preferred solution. However, it's important to note that, for now, this solution doesn't appear to work when you're using the new vector drawable types as the source.

Comment: @haagmm this solution needs API >= 21. Also it works for vectors too.

Comment: And it should not work with vectors, the root tag is `bitmap`. There are other ways to color vectors. Perhaps someone could add vector coloring here too...

Answer (score 11):

Most of the solutions in this thread either use a newer API, or use reflection, or use intensive view lookup to get to the inflated `MenuItem`.

However, there's a more elegant approach to do that. You need a custom Toolbar, as your "apply custom tint" use case does not play well with public styling/theming API.

```
public class MyToolbar extends Toolbar {
    ... some constructors, extracting mAccentColor from AttrSet, etc

    @Override
    public void inflateMenu(@MenuRes int resId) {
        super.inflateMenu(resId);
        Menu menu = getMenu();
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
            MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
            Drawable icon = item.getIcon();
            if (icon != null) {
                item.setIcon(applyTint(icon));
            }
        }
    }
    void applyTint(Drawable icon){
        icon.setColorFilter(
           new PorterDuffColorFilter(mAccentColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        );
    }

}
```

Just make sure you call in your Activity/Fragment code:

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.some_menu);
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(someListener);
```

No reflection, no view lookup, and not so much code, huh?

And now you can ignore the ridiculous `onCreateOptionsMenu/onOptionsItemSelected`.

Comment: Technically, you are doing a view lookup. You're iterating the views and ensuring they are not null. ;)

Comment: You're definitely right in a way :-) Nonetheless, `Menu#getItem()` complexity is O(1) in the toolbar, because items are stored in ArrayList. Which is different from `View#findViewById` traversal (which I referred to as _view lookup_ in my answer), complexity of which is far from being constant :-)

Comment: Agreed, in fact, I did a very similar thing. I'm still shocked that Android hasn't streamlined all this after so many years…

Comment: How can I change the overflow icon and hamburger icon's colors with this approach?

Answer (score 9):

Here is the solution that I use; you can call it after onPrepareOptionsMenu() or the equivalent place. The reason for mutate() is if you happen to use the icons in more than one location; without the mutate, they will all take on the same tint.

```
public class MenuTintUtils {
    public static void tintAllIcons(Menu menu, final int color) {
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); ++i) {
            final MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
            tintMenuItemIcon(color, item);
            tintShareIconIfPresent(color, item);
        }
    }

    private static void tintMenuItemIcon(int color, MenuItem item) {
        final Drawable drawable = item.getIcon();
        if (drawable != null) {
            final Drawable wrapped = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
            drawable.mutate();
            DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapped, color);
            item.setIcon(drawable);
        }
    }

    private static void tintShareIconIfPresent(int color, MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getActionView() != null) {
            final View actionView = item.getActionView();
            final View expandActivitiesButton = actionView.findViewById(R.id.expand_activities_button);
            if (expandActivitiesButton != null) {
                final ImageView image = (ImageView) expandActivitiesButton.findViewById(R.id.image);
                if (image != null) {
                    final Drawable drawable = image.getDrawable();
                    final Drawable wrapped = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
                    drawable.mutate();
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapped, color);
                    image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This won't take care of the overflow, but for that, you can do this:

Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    ...
    android:theme="@style/myToolbarTheme" />
```

Styles:

```
<style name="myToolbarTheme">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

This works as of appcompat v23.1.0.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

        val inflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.player_menu, menu)

        //tinting menu item:
        val typedArray = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(IntArray(1) { android.R.attr.textColorSecondary })
        val textColor = typedArray.getColor(0, 0)
        typedArray.recycle()

        val item = menu?.findItem(R.id.action_chapters)
        val icon = item?.icon

        icon?.setColorFilter(textColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        item?.icon = icon
        return true
    }
```

Or you can use tint in drawable xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:tint="?android:textColorSecondary"
    android:viewportWidth="384"
    android:viewportHeight="384">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"

        android:pathData="M0,277.333h384v42.667h-384z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M0,170.667h384v42.667h-384z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M0,64h384v42.667h-384z" />
</vector>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
    //One item tint
    menu.get(itemId).getIcon().setTint(Color);
   //or all
    for(int i=0;i<menu.size();i++){
    menu.get(i).getIcon().setTint(Color);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).