# How to change OverflowButton's and BackArrow's color?

Tags: android, material-design, android-xml, android-theme

I'm developing a **material design** app.

The Toolbar's color is white and the `titleText`'s & `tabTitleText`'s is `#2196F3`. But the **OverflowButton**'s & **BackArrow**'s color is not changing.

Here are the screenshot:

OverflowButton's color has not changed:
[image: OverflowButton's color has not changed]

BackArrow's color has not changed:
[image: BackArrow's color has not changed]

Here's `MainActivity.java` file's code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    int normalTabTextColor = Color.parseColor("#64B5F6");
    int selectedTabTextColor = Color.parseColor("#2196F3");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            // Call some material design APIs here
            // enable transitions
            getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
        } else {
            // Implement this feature without material design
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(normalTabTextColor, selectedTabTextColor);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        /*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_profile:
                // Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
                    // Call some material design APIs here
                    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(profileIntent,
                            ActivityOptions
                                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
                } else {
                    // Implement this feature without material design
                    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(profileIntent);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_support_development:
                // Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
                    // Call some material design APIs here
                    Intent supportDevelopmentIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SupportDevelopmentActivity.class);
                    startActivity(supportDevelopmentIntent,
                            ActivityOptions
                                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
                } else {
                    // Implement this feature without material design
                    Intent supportDevelopmentIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SupportDevelopmentActivity.class);
                    startActivity(supportDevelopmentIntent);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
                    // Call some material design APIs here
                    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(settingsIntent,
                            ActivityOptions
                                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
                } else {
                    // Implement this feature without material design
                    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(settingsIntent);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_help:
                // Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
                    // Call some material design APIs here
                    Intent helpIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelpActivity.class);
                    startActivity(helpIntent,
                            ActivityOptions
                                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
                } else {
                    // Implement this feature without material design
                    Intent helpIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelpActivity.class);
                    startActivity(helpIntent);
                }
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Accept a Request";
                case 1:
                    return "Post a Request";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's `colors.xml` file's code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#1E88E5</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="textColorPrimary">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="textColorSecondary">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="textColorTertiary">#2196F3</color>
</resources>
```

Here's `v21/styles.xml` file's code:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/textColorTertiary</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="OverflowButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Here's `values/styles.xml` file's code:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/textColorTertiary</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowButtonStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <style name="OverflowButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I really don't know how to change their color.

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the following style:

```
<style name="AppThemeOverlay.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/actionbar_icon</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/actionbar_title</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/actionbar_subtitle</item>
</style>
```

Apply it in your theme via

```
<item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppThemeOverlay.ActionBar</item>
```

or in your layout on `Toolbar`/`AppBarLayout`

```
android:theme="@style/AppThemeOverlay.ActionBar"
```

Note: This will only color the icons provided by AppCompat library (back, clear, search, overflow...). For other icons you'll have to do something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/a/29916353/2444099.

Answer (score 0):

```
For overflow menu button color change, this may help 

      <style name="OverflowButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
            <item name="android:src"><add your drawable of your color here></item>
            <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>
      </style>

    similarly for back button

          <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
                <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
                <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
                <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
                <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
                <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>
                <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/textColorTertiary</item>
                <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/<add your drawable here for back button> </item>
                <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowButtonStyle</item>
            </style>
```

Comment: what should I put in `android:src` & `android:actionModeCloseDrawable`? Can you please explain?

Comment: @HammadNasir in style itself , and drawable should be put in respective drawable folder

Comment: Can you please suggest me a code snippet to put into it?

Comment: So just replace your style.xml with the above style.xml and provide drawable of any color you want( you must have png image of that drawable) and run your application, it will work

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of the back arrow you can try this code:

```
    final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Put it into your `OnCreate()` method under `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`;

Hope it helps :D

Comment: By doing this, the arrow has disappeared! What to do?

Comment: @HammadNasir, I think you already found the answer. You may need to add these lines after the previous code:

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`
`getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`