# How to set the color of the vector asset?

Tags: java, android

I just want to set the colour of the **vector asset**. I have searched for it but doesn't seem to be work for me. and I don't want to change it from XML, I want to change it in my MainActivity.java, or I say programmatically.is there any method for this?

Here is my Code

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.add("Image");
    menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_camera_alt_black_24dp);
    menuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    //something like this
    //menuItem.setIconColor(Color.WHITE);
    return true;
}
```

I am searching something for formatting the icon colour.

*I mentioned it that I don't want to do this using XML.And as well `android:tint` does not work for me*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MenuItem tinting on AppCompat Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780046/menuitem-tinting-on-appcompat-toolbar)

Comment: No this doesn't work , i mentioned i don't want to do it with xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code

```
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_camera_alt_black_24dp, null);
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.WHITE);
menuItem.setIcon(drawable);
```

Comment: @ShivamSingh if answer will help you then don't forgot to mark it as right answer. Happy coding..!!

Comment: @ShivamSingh yes you can.

Answer (score 2):

```
ivImageView.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing colour for a Vector Drawable should be for an `ImageView` or `Drawable`:

```
yourImageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color_white), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

This will work for Vector images `ImageView` or Drawable as `ImageView`

Comment: sorry sir, no xml i want to change the color onButtonClick.

Answer (score 1):

```
menuItem.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE , PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```