# MenuItem tint for all apis - iconTint for apis > 26 -

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I would like to set iconTint for the menu item as you see below but I have a warning "Attribute iconTint is only used in API level 26 and higher" So is there another way to set tint of menu item icon.

Thanks!

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_schedule"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter_list_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="@color/black"
        android:title="@string/filter"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I've already found a solution.

By handling it with DrawableCompat :

```
 menu?.getItem(0)?.icon?.let {
            DrawableCompat.setTint(
                it,
                ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black)
            )
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get `Unresolved reference: DrawableCompat`

Comment: seems you don't have the color, add black color to your colors file or change it

Comment: Using the support library XML attribute `app:iconTint=` in your menu XML is probably the simpler solution now. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54961263